# How to check as boolean data if user has Google Drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

My application I'm making must have to able to download files from Google Drive. So, The app should check that user has Google Drive. One class named DriveDetector is role of checking this facts. Actually, And basically all of Android Phone have Google Application that including Google Drive. Android users cannot remove the Google Drive completely, but they're able to be Google Drive invisible. HOW TO CHECK GOOGLE DRIVE IS ACTIVATED ON THE USER'S PHONE? Thanks to read my question post.

```js
import android.content.Context;

public class DriveDetector {
    private Context context;

    public DriveDetector (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean hasGoogleDrive() {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check if application is already installed in phone or not by following:

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

you can call this method to check for google drive like this:

```
boolean hasDrive = isAppInstalled(context, "com.google.android.apps.doc");
```